# Mix ASP.NET & php, Php just for page templates?

Tags: php, asp.net, html

For my website:

1. I use ASP.NET for the restricted access pages requiring user login. (this point is firm)
2. I want to use html for the public pages, to have more freedom?, and to make pages load faster.
3. I'm thinking to make the public pages php, for the only reason of page-template support, as many pages will need the same layout.

As **I'm new to all these technologies**, does this sound sensible, or may it even create problems or adverse performance? The public pages will not be very advanced. I will use some jQuery and js libraries for image effects etc, otherwise just plain text and menus.

I'm currently using Aptana Studio 3, which doesn't have page templates. Should I swap to Dreamweaver just to get templates? It seems very bloated, I like to just code html and css directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not replace the php part with asp.net as well? I mean you can use the same master page if you want to. Mixing the two technology can be both troublesome to maintain and debug for.

What advantages does using php have over asp.net for this project?

Comment: idk, it was mostly a gut-feeling, like that ASP.NET can be slow to load, that's why I wanted to avoid it. But maybe that's not true. So are there any justified reasons why one would potentially avoid ASP.NET for the full site?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't mix technologies like PHP and ASP.NET (unless if I REALLY have to) If you have moderate hardware ASP.NET is not slow at all. You can look at caching support and/or compiling the MSIL directly into binary...

Comment: What is the problem with that? It will be completely different sections of the site. Like a bank login, do they really use the same technology for public vs logged-in pages?  I still can't see why this is problematic or even why it interferes at all? (Assuming I don't try to share the templates between php/asp)

Comment: There are none, except the overhead to maintain 2 technologies. 1 less technology dependency. But otherwise why not?

Answer (score 0):

ASP .NET is also a page templating technology. You don't need PHP, and for consistency I wouldn't mix them, unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Both PHP and ASP are scripting languages.

I don't see why you want to make use of **both** in the same project.
But of course, they have both their strenghts and weaknesses.

The most important question, is what does your application **server** supports?
Some Linux-based servers don't run ASP, and some Windows-servers don't support PHP.

I have quite good experience PHP and ASP, and I like **ASP MVC 3** a lot lately.
It has standard support for authentication, can make use of different page templating syntaxes and had good online support.